# How to rename route key with model binding in PHP Laravel 8 (incorrect plurals)?

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, model-binding

I have a Laravel 8 project where I have a model called `FieldOfStudy`, but the problem is that the plural of this class's name should be *fields of study* instead of *field of studies*. That causes a problem when creating an API endpoint with the following route:

```php
Route::apiResource('fields-of-study', FieldOfStudyController::class);
```

The thing is, that I have a resource controller's method `FieldOfStudyController::show()` like this:

```php
public function show(FieldOfStudy $fieldOfStudy)
{
  dd($fieldOfStudy);
}
```

This will show me, that `$fieldOfStudy` contains a "blank" model, not the desired instance from the database. When I checked the route parameters, I found out, that the id of the model is stored as `fields_of_study` instead of `field_of_study`.

I tried to rename the parameter (didn't work - binding fails):

```php
Route::apiResource('fields-of-study', FieldOfStudyController::class)->parameter('fields_of_study','field_of_study');
```

When I rename the parameter of the `show()` method, it works, but it's not really pretty:

```php
public function show(FieldOfStudy $fieldsOfStudy) { }
```

How can I properly adjust my code to:

1. keep the URI in the correct plural (i.e. `/fields-of-study`),
2. keep the `show()` parameter name in the correct singular (i.e. `$fieldOfStudy`) and
3. don't mess the model-binding mechanism for typed parameters like `show(FieldOfStudy $fieldOfStudy)`?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you go with option 4, rename your database table and Model to `study_fields` and `StudyField`? This is an interesting naming case that I haven't seen or dealt with before, interesting find 

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate Laravel [explicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding):

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::model('fields-of-study', FieldOfStudy::class);
}
```